Controller doesn't work after LoadScene in Unity using input system, but works perfectly in his own scene?
Edit: I made a screen record since it's easier to show rather than explain
I'm making a multiplayer game in unity and i wanted to implement the possibility to use a controller to move the cursor in my MainMenu scene. The project right now has 3 scenes:

Setup scene: just a black panel with a loading text, i use it as my first scene, to initialize some network stuff and to load the mainMenu scene.
MainMenu scene: the menu where i want to be able to move the cursor with both my mouse and my controller. It has some buttons such as "Host Lobby" or "Join Lobby"
Game scene: the scene of the actual game, yet to be implemented.

In my MainMenu scene I created a GameObject called CursorUI, added a UI image to it to give the virtual cursor a sprite, added the Virtual Mouse script from the input system and a script to not make the cursor go out of border and scale with the canvas and a script to interchange between virtual cursor moved with the controller and the cursor moved with the mouse.
//script to interchange between controller and mouse
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class CursorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static CursorController instance;
    // References to Input Actions
    public InputAction mouseMoveAction;
    public InputAction controllerMoveAction;

    // Reference to the cursor GameObject
    public GameObject virtualCursor;

    // Track the last active input method
    private bool usingMouse = true; // Start with mouse as default

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Enable the input actions
        mouseMoveAction.Enable();
        controllerMoveAction.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Disable the input actions
        mouseMoveAction.Disable();
        controllerMoveAction.Disable();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Check if mouse and controller movements are active
        bool mouseActive = mouseMoveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>() != Vector2.zero;
        bool controllerActive = controllerMoveAction.ReadValue<Vector2>() != Vector2.zero;

        // Determine the active input method
        if (controllerActive)
        {
            usingMouse = false;
            Cursor.visible = false;
            virtualCursor.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (mouseActive)
        {
            usingMouse = true;
            Cursor.visible = true;
            virtualCursor.SetActive(false);
        }
        else
        {
            // If neither mouse nor controller is active, maintain current state
            if (usingMouse)
            {
                Cursor.visible = true;
                virtualCursor.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.visible = false;
                virtualCursor.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ToggleFunctionality(bool enable)
    {
        // Enable or disable input actions and cursor functionality
        if (enable)
        {
            mouseMoveAction.Enable();
            controllerMoveAction.Enable();
            virtualCursor.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            mouseMoveAction.Disable();
            controllerMoveAction.Disable();
            virtualCursor.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

When I load the MainMenu scene only, it all works perfectly, but when i try to either load the game from the setup scene or build and run the whole project, after the setup scene load the mainMenu scene, my controller dies and even if i tried again to load only the mainMenu scene, the controller wouldn't work, only my mouse cursor works. The only way to make it work again is to relaunch unity.
//script in Setup scene to load the MainMenu
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Netcode;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneLoaderManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadMainScene());
    }

    IEnumerator LoadMainScene()
    {
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => NetworkManager.Singleton != null);
        CursorController cursorController = FindObjectOfType<CursorController>();
        if (cursorController != null)
            cursorController.ToggleFunctionality(true);
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }

}


Any ideas what the problem could be?
_Edit: I found the problem, the controller keeps disconnecting when loading the scene. I saw it in the Input Debug, I have Disconnected(1) ->Controller
I implemented this code in the setup scene to try to reconnect the controller when it disconnects, but it still disconnects
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
using System.Collections;

public class GlobalInputManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        InputSystem.onDeviceChange += OnDeviceChange;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        InputSystem.onDeviceChange -= OnDeviceChange;
    }

    private void OnDeviceChange(InputDevice device, InputDeviceChange change)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Device change detected: {device} - Change: {change}");

        if (change == InputDeviceChange.Disconnected)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Device disconnected: {device}");
            // Attempt to re-enable the device after a short delay
            StartCoroutine(ReconnectDevice(device));
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator ReconnectDevice(InputDevice device)
    {
        // Wait for a short period before attempting to reconnect
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        if (!device.enabled)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Re-enabling device: {device}");
            InputSystem.EnableDevice(device);
        }
    }

    private void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject); // Keep this GameObject alive across scene changes
    }
}

how can i stop the controller from disconnecting?

do yhou have the event system?  did you have the first script in the second scene?

@BugFinder yes to both your questions, i have event system in both of my scenes
